# Who actually runs the 'Other Springfield'?

Tags: simpsons-tapped-out

When starting out the game, and you get access to The Other Springfield as a friend, who actually runs it? I notice it keeps getting built up and up, and I even find Sideshow Bob in there once in a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The developers of the game played the Other Springfield.  It's not so much of an AI as it is a pre-programmed series of events.  This is why there are versions of it that are available at various levels.

[Source](http://tstogame.com/tag/other-springfield/)

Comment: Link expired :-(

Answer (score 0):

It's the computer AI. Probably so you have at least one "friend" in case you don't have any Facebook friends or whatever to add. The AI must have lots of money since it splurges on everything!

Comment: Pretty advanced ai then. Any evidence for this point? Cause I've seen things move too

Comment: No evidence unless you can see the underlying source code, but since everyone has an "Other Springfield" which is created close to  when you start out, it stands to reason that it is part of the program. Whether or not it is a built-in script or some AI mechanism is harder to unless you could get several players to compare their Other Springfield under similar circumstances.